# Passing 'sqlite3 *const *' (aka 'struct sqlite3 *const *') to parameter of type 'sqlite3 **' (aka 'struct sqlite3 **') discards qualifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

An warning message appear while I am using my database sqlite. It appears on the **"&database"**
Any ideas ?

```
 sqlite3 *database;

NSLog(@"Open Database : %@", path);

            // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
            if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Open Database OK");


                NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"....
```

Comment: Where have you defined method to get db path?

Comment: Hmm. I cannot produce that error with this code. I get that precise compile-time error message if I define `database` like so, though: `sqlite3 * const database;`. Now, I don't think you would have done that and not shared it with us, but I suspect something in your definition of `database`. But the problem is not in the above code. Perhaps you can share more details about where you have this code, etc.

Comment: Thx for your help, it was because I put the use of the database in a dispatch_async, and the declaration of the database outside that dispatch_async. I didn't know I couldn't do that...

Comment: @HotAppleCyber - He's using Objective-C, as he indicated in not only his code sample, but his question's tags, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : It was because I put the declaration of the database outside a dispatch.

Here is my old code more complete than upstairs :

```
sqlite3 *database;
NSString *path = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tva.sqlite"];

dispatch_queue_t searchTVAQueue = dispatch_queue_create("searchTVA", NULL);
        dispatch_async(searchTVAQueue, ^{
NSLog(@"Open Database : %@", path);

            if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Open Database OK");

                NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"....
                ...
```

Here is the good code :

```
dispatch_queue_t searchTVAQueue = dispatch_queue_create("searchTVA", NULL);
        dispatch_async(searchTVAQueue, ^{

sqlite3 *database;
NSString *path = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tva.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"Open Database : %@", path);

            if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Open Database OK");

                NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"....
                ...
```

I just included the database declaration directly in the dispatch_async.